# css scale translated element without moving

Tags: css, html, svg, scale

I would like to animate an svg element and let it scale(2). This works fine but the problem is that my element has an 'x' and 'y' value. Because of this the scale moves the element to a different position.

But I would like to scale it without moving it to a different position. The 'x' and 'y' values are defined somewhere else and I don't would like to "hardcode" the values in my css.
And I don't want to use JS it shoudl be plane css if possible.

Code:

```
.hello {
             transition: 1s;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
margin: 100px;
background-color: red;
transform-origin: center center;
position:relative;

        }
         .hello:hover {

transform: scale(4);
}


  <use
   id="=test"

   xlink:href="#but"
   x="100" y="20"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
 class="hello">
  <title
     id="title31">
            I am an example toolTip
        </title>
</use>
```

A code example can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/6agd23cL/3/

Answer (score 1):

remove the x and y attributes and increase the translate on the parent `<g>` element to compensate.

```css
 .hello {
     transition: 1s;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 100px;
 background-color: red;
 transform-origin: center center;
 position:relative;
   
   }
    .hello:hover {
    
 transform: scale(4);
    }
```

```html
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
  
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 
   id="target"
   width="3600"
   height="4100"
   style="top:0;left:0;"
   version="1.1">
  <defs
     id="styles">
    <g
       id="but">
      <style
         id="style11">
                .cls-1{fill:#ffc60b;}.cls-2{stroke:#231f20;stroke-width:0.5px;}.cls-3{fill:#fff;opacity:0.1;}
            </style>
      <rect
         id="Frame"
         width="12"
         height="12"
         x="0.25"
         y="0.25"
         class="cls-1"
         rx="2"
         ry="2" />
      <circle
         id="circle14"
         cx="6.25"
         cy="6.25"
         r="4.5"
         class="cls-2" />
      <circle
         id="Highlight"
         cx="6.25"
         cy="6.25"
         r="3"
         class="cls-3" />
    </g>
  </defs>

  <g
     id="view"
     transform="translate(114.386917,29.7722462)">

     <use
       id="=test"
       
       xlink:href="#but"

       width="100%"
       height="100%"
 class="hello">
      <title
         id="title31">
                I am an example toolTip
            </title>
    </use>

  </g>
</svg>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, that would work, but my problem is that in my <g> normally multiple "use" are in and not only one. And i really would like to avoid to put an additional <g> around each element

I could try to use instead of x and y the transform option but then the class will overwrite this with teh scale and the element is no longer placed at the correct position.